# Triangle inequality- complex

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

I am trying to prove the triangle inequality purely algebraically.

Let $z=x+iy$, $w=u+iv$.

Then,

$|z+w|^2$=$|(x+u)+i(y+v)|^2$=$(x+u)^2+(y+v)^2$=$x^2+2xu+u^2+y^2+2yv+v^2$

I tried the other way:

$(|z|+|w|)^2$=$(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+\sqrt{u^2+v^2})^2$=$x^2+y^2+u^2+v^2+2 \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \sqrt{u^2+v^2}$

I'm trying to do this without using the complex conjugate or anything.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality:
$$
\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \sqrt{u^2+v^2}\geq xu+yv
$$

---

To prove it directly:
$$
\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \sqrt{u^2+v^2}\geq xu+yv\implies\\
x^2u^2+x^2v^2+y^2u^2+y^2v^2\geq x^2u^2+2xvyu+y^2v^2\implies\\
x^2v^2+y^2u^2 - 2xvyu\geq 0 \implies\\
(xv-yu)^2 \geq 0 \\
$$

Comment: Is there any way to do it without using the inequality?

Comment: I added something to the answer.